# OpenGL ES Framebuffer size format is invalid

Tags: qt, opengl-es, egl, qt5.12

After I upgraded my Embedded Qt 5.9.8 Application to Qt version 5.12.8 I got the warning "Setting framebuffer size is only available with DRM atomic API".
The application run on a i.MX6 Solo System On Module (OS Yocto Warrior Linux, Kernel 4.19).

I fixed this warning by setting the environment variable QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_ATOMIC.
Then I got "Framebuffer size format is invalid".

How can I set the Framebuffer size format?

I tried to solve it with QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH and QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT.
But I still get the warning.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Setting QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH and QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT fixes the incorrect scaling (DPI issue I guess), but it does not get rid of that `Framebuffer size format is invalid.` error.